# Node.js serving HTML file doesn't find referenced files

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to make a simple game using Node.js and HTML. I want to be able to run the game locally (so localhost). But when I start my Node server, only the HTML content is rendered - my images don't show up and the JS is not loaded. I reference JavaScript files, CSS files and images in the HTML code. Not sure why the server cannot reference these from within the HTML.

Here is my server code:

```
const path = require('path')
const http = require('http')
var fs = require('fs')

//Set port number:
const port = 3000

const requestHandler = (request, response) => {
    console.log(request.url)

    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.end(fs.readFileSync('game.html'));

}

const server = http.createServer(requestHandler)
server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Error: ', err);
    }

    console.log(`Game started\nGo to http://localhost:3000 to play\n`);
    console.log(`Server is listening on ${port}...`);
})
```

Can anyone tell me how I can get my images/JS loaded?
TIA

Comment: It looks like your requestHandler only returns your html page in response to every request it gets, and ignores the requested URL. You'll need to add code in it to look at the request.url, determine which file is being requested, and deliver it.  You might also look at node express, a framework for building an ordinary web server from node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not serving the static content correctly (i.e. images, CSS). Consider what happens when one navigates to `http://localhost:3000/some_image.png` - they will be served game.html!

You need to account for users requesting that content in your `requestHandler` by for example reading the file they want with `fs.readFileSync(request.url)`. Remember to check that they can only request files you want them to be able to read!

Comment: This worked, problem solved. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need static handlers to return static content. Check this
https://www.pabbly.com/tutorials/node-js-http-module-serving-static-files-html-css-images/.

Also, if your application is going to be huge then use some middle-ware like Express. (https://expressjs.com/)

Comment: I fixed my problem by using you suggestion and returning content by url. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you use express framework, you can use static rendering:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

where 'public' is the folder name